# Ошибка: если заработать от 1000 баллов репутации, то оповещение отображается обрезанным на мобильной версии

Tags: дефект, дизайн, репутация, мобильная-версия

Вчера заработал более 1000 баллов репутации за ответы на два вопроса:

- [Как получить путь пересечения двух путей SVG программно?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/926381)
- [Как сделать адаптивный svg?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/925152)

и получил вот такое обрезанное оповещение *на мобильной версии* StackOverflow:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На изображении слева – обычное отображение, а справа – если потянуть страницу пальцем. Сначала кажется, что заработал всего 102 балла, если не потянуть.

Думаю, будет достаточно отображать это посередине родительского элемента, чтобы исправить ошибку.

Answer (score 3):

Не надо столько репы за раз брать и будет всё норм :) Если серьёзно, то это вряд ли будут фиксить из-за достаточной редкости подобных ситуаций, более того, мобильная версия планомерно замещается сайтом с адаптивным дизайном (см. ссылку внизу страницы в полной версии сайта). Ну, а если уж и править, то, имхо, правильнее сделать не просто центровку, а выводить в паре с суфиксом, как это показано внутри самого выпадающего окна 1.1К. Текст должен быть короче.